# what does getpid() call doing in time measuring with mach_absolute_time

Tags: iphone, macos, timer

The article itself is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html

Right after calling of mach_absolute_time there is a call of getpid(). According to documentation this function returns an id of the calling process. I don't understand why is is here and about what inaccurate results author is talking in context of time's measuring.

Here is the code I'm wondering about:

```
uint64_t GetPIDTimeInNanoseconds(void)
{
    uint64_t        start;
    uint64_t        end;
    uint64_t        elapsed;
    uint64_t        elapsedNano;
    static mach_timebase_info_data_t    sTimebaseInfo;

    // Start the clock.

    start = mach_absolute_time();

    // Call getpid. This will produce inaccurate results because 
    // we're only making a single system call. For more accurate 
    // results you should call getpid multiple times and average 
    // the results.

    (void) getpid();

    // Stop the clock.

    end = mach_absolute_time();

    // Calculate the duration.

    elapsed = end - start;

    // Convert to nanoseconds.

    // If this is the first time we've run, get the timebase.
    // We can use denom == 0 to indicate that sTimebaseInfo is 
    // uninitialised because it makes no sense to have a zero 
    // denominator is a fraction.

    if ( sTimebaseInfo.denom == 0 ) {
        (void) mach_timebase_info(&sTimebaseInfo);
    }

    // Do the maths. We hope that the multiplication doesn't 
    // overflow; the price you pay for working in fixed point.

    elapsedNano = elapsed * sTimebaseInfo.numer / sTimebaseInfo.denom;

    return elapsedNano;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The author has provided sample code showing how to make precise timing measurements. I believe he/she has used getpid() simply as an example of a function call to be measured (the function name is GetPIDTimeInNanoseconds).

With regards to the inaccuracy comment, I think the author is suggesting that you take multiple readings and average the results for a higher degree of accuracy. For example, instead of starting and stopping the clock once perhaps you could do something like:

```
int numberOfReadings = 5;
uint64_t elapsedTimeAccumulated = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfReadings; i++) {
    start = mach_absolute_time();
    (void) getpid();
    end = mach_absolute_time();
    elapsedTimeAccumulated += end - start;
}
// Average
elapsed = elapsedTimeAccumulated / numberOfReadings;
```